# PHP/Ajax Default values

Tags: php, ajax, default-value

I give up. Can someone please give me a hand here. Currently, I have a page that verifies the users payment address, then when they click continue verifies the shipping address. It highlights the default address. I want it to post the default value of the payment address and skip to the skipping address on page load.

So i have it here where when you click the continue button it submits the billing address and moves to the shipping address.

```
// Payment Address  
$('#button-payment-address').live('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_address/validate',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#payment-address input[type=\'text\'], #payment-address input[type=\'password\'], #payment-address input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #payment-address input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #payment-address input[type=\'hidden\'], #payment-address select'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-payment-address').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#button-payment-address').after('<span class="wait">&nbsp;<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif" alt="" /></span>');
        },  
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-payment-address').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.wait').remove();
        },          
        success: function(json) {
            $('.warning, .error').remove();

            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            } else if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['warning']) {
                    $('#payment-address .checkout-content').prepend('<div class="warning" style="display: none;">' + json['error']['warning'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                    $('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
                }

                if (json['error']['firstname']) {
                    $('#payment-address input[name=\'firstname\']').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['firstname'] + '</span>');
                }

                if (json['error']['lastname']) {
                    $('#payment-address input[name=\'lastname\']').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['lastname'] + '</span>');
                }   

                if (json['error']['telephone']) {
                    $('#payment-address input[name=\'telephone\']').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['telephone'] + '</span>');
                }       

                if (json['error']['company_id']) {
                    $('#payment-address input[name=\'company_id\']').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['company_id'] + '</span>');
                }   

                if (json['error']['tax_id']) {
                    $('#payment-address input[name=\'tax_id\']').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['tax_id'] + '</span>');
                }   

                if (json['error']['address_1']) {
                    $('#payment-address input[name=\'address_1\']').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['address_1'] + '</span>');
                }   

                if (json['error']['city']) {
                    $('#payment-address input[name=\'city\']').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['city'] + '</span>');
                }   

                if (json['error']['postcode']) {
                    $('#payment-address input[name=\'postcode\']').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['postcode'] + '</span>');
                }   

                if (json['error']['country']) {
                    $('#payment-address select[name=\'country_id\']').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['country'] + '</span>');
                }   

                if (json['error']['zone']) {
                    $('#payment-address select[name=\'zone_id\']').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['zone'] + '</span>');
                }
            } else {
                <?php if ($shipping_required) { ?>
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_address',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#shipping-address .checkout-content').html(html);

                        $('#payment-address .checkout-content').slideUp('slow');

                        $('#shipping-address .checkout-content').slideDown('slow');

                        $('#payment-address .checkout-heading a').remove();
                        $('#shipping-address .checkout-heading a').remove();
                        $('#shipping-method .checkout-heading a').remove();
                        $('#payment-method .checkout-heading a').remove();

                        $('#payment-address .checkout-heading').append('<a><?php echo $text_modify; ?></a>');   
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
                <?php } else { ?>
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_method',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#payment-method .checkout-content').html(html);

                        $('#payment-address .checkout-content').slideUp('slow');

                        $('#payment-method .checkout-content').slideDown('slow');

                        $('#payment-address .checkout-heading a').remove();
                        $('#payment-method .checkout-heading a').remove();

                        $('#payment-address .checkout-heading').append('<a><?php echo $text_modify; ?></a>');   
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }); 
                <?php } ?>

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_address',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#payment-address .checkout-content').html(html);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });             
            }     
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    }); 
});
```

and I thought it would be as simple as replacing

```
$('#button-payment-address').live('click', function() {
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

but that does not work. eventually all sections will load defaults and i will have just one button that submits all the forms, but obviously if i cant even get the one section to accept the default i cant really move on.

Comment: Not replacing...$(document).ready(function() {$('#button-payment-address').live('click', function() {}); });

Comment: This doesnt seem to get the default value. it is still waiting on me to click the button-payment-address button and I am trying to eliminate the need for it

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you could clarify which part of it isn't working. Without knowing that though... it's possible that if you're using a version of jQuery that's 1.7 or later, using [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) might work, since [.live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated at this point.

Comment: well, if i just change it to $(document).ready(function() { the billing address does slide up, and the shipping address displays, but then i continue through the rest of the steps, get to the end, and it says no payment address selected and throws me back to the top. it never gets the payment address. But again, using the same code, but using $('#button-payment-address').live('click', function() { it goes through fine. and I am using 1.7.1